# Values I want to plot don't show in the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

So I'm guessing this is going to be a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.
The problem I'm having isn't really huge but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.

I got a ndarray of datetime objects as xvalues and a ndarray of float values as yvalues.

```
def drawWindow():

    # Getting our root window in tkinter
    root = tkin.Tk()

    # Selecting the figure type
    fig = plt.figure(1)

    # Setting the plot on interactive so it can be updated
    plt.ion()

    xValues = np.array([guiClass.__getX__("1/9/2019", "2/11/2019")])
    yValues = np.array([guiClass.__getY__("temperatuurGC ","1/9/2019", "2/11/2019")])

    plt.plot(xValues, yValues) # X values, Y values
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    plotWidget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

def update():
     yValues = np.array([guiClass.__getY__("temperatuurGC ","1/9/2019", "2/11/2019")])         
    plt.plot(xValues, yValues)
    fig.canvas.draw()

    plotWidget.grid(row=0, column=0)
    tkin.Button(root, text="Update", command=update).grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

in this example, the values in the `yValues` `ndarray` are `[10.7, 10.5, 10., 9.7, 9.9, 9.7, 9.9, 9.8, 10., 9.8, 9.9]`

my output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzAQr.png)

I would like my values to be shown in the plot but it doesn't work in the way I'm trying, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mind the difference between `np.array([some_array])` and `np.array(some_array)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest what is the difference? From the documentation I can't get what would be the difference. A simple test I made: np.array([1,2,3]) --> array([1, 2, 3]) --- np.array(np.array([1,2,3])) --> array([1, 2, 3]).

Comment: @Robyc The difference is `np.array([[1,2,3]])` versus `np.array([1,2,3])`. The first is a 2D column array, the latter is a 1D row.